# html canvas set x and y coordinates for mouseup events

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I was wondering how you would set up the X and Y coordinates for an event to occur after you drag an image and release the mouse in that area. Something like a game where you pick one of three choices. Plenty of tutorials show you how to execute a mouseup event, but no one seems to tell you about setting coordinates for an event.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example...http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/qU3gq/

Let's say you have an image like this and you want someone to click on the animal of their choice:

[image]

This is how the animals are horizontally arranged.

```
The bird     part of the image starts at x==0   and ends at x==121.
The bear     part of the image starts at x==122 and ends at x==231.
The camel    part of the image starts at x==232 and ends at x==325.
The elephant part of the image starts at x==326 and ends at x==475.
The zebra    part of the image starts at x==476 and ends at x==600.
```

So you can create a javascript object representing each animal and put them in an array:

```
var animals=[];
animals.push({minX:0,maxX:121,name:"Bird"});
animals.push({minX:122,maxX:231,name:"Bear"});
animals.push({minX:232,maxX:325,name:"Camel"});
animals.push({minX:324,maxX:475,name:"Elephant"});
animals.push({minX:476,maxX:600,name:"Zebra"});
```

Then you can listen for the mouseUp event and calculate the mouseX & mouseY where the mouse was released like this:

```
// listen for mouseUp events

canvas.onmouseup=handleMouseup;

// canvas is a reference to the canvas element
// BB is the bounding box of the canvas element (as adjusted for scrolling)

function handleMouseUp(e){

    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-BB.left);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-BB.top);

    ...
```

And in mouseUp you can test if the mouse was released inside a particular animals area like this:

```
var selectedAnimal="None";
for(var i=0;i<animals.length;i++){
    var animal=animals[i];
    if(mouseX>=animal.minX && mouseX<=animal.maxX){
        selectedAnimal=animal.name;
    }
}
alert("You released the mouse over the "+selectedAnimal);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable that acts as a flag (true/false) for your engine to signal that an image is being dragged and another one that identifies the image. When the mouse is released, clear the flag. Define the mouse event methods with jQuery or manually in javascript. Did you want some code for an example? I hope I understood your question right.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

This is just some pseudocode that I threw together; you should be able to figure out how to implement it yourself as most of your problem is logical.

```
<script>
    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var imageXDropped = 0; // optional; depends on your logic/algorithm
    var imageYDropped = 0; // optional; depends on your logic/algorithm
    var imageDragging = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myCanvas").mousemove(function(event){
        var rect = $("#myCanvas").getBoundingClientRect();
        mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
        mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

        if(imageDragging){
          //set image position to mouse position
        }
      });

     //image mousedown function(event){
        imageDragging = true;
     }
     //image mouseup function(event){
        imageDragging = false;
        imageXDropped = event.clientX - $("#myCanvas").getBoundingClientRect().left; (mouse x position)
        imageYDropped = event.clientY - $("#myCanvas").getBoundingClientRect().top; (mouse y position)
     }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I threw together an example, but I didn't want to code the whole thing because it depends on your engine. You should understand the basic syntax idea and figure out the logic.